# Trying to figure out how to get current location to work

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have finally figured out how to get the directions to make a route when the start location and the end location are filled out. I would like for when they load my site it automatically takes their current location and plots them on the map or insert their location in the start location input field. I have tried many ways of doing this but i believe it is interfering with my current script.

PS: Im a newb to this site and couldnt figure out how to post my code write so here is the link to my page. http://travismichael.net/mobile_app/map.html

Please if anyone can help me out or has any pointers that would be great:)

Answer (score 0):

Use geolocation [Google demo](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocate/geolocate.html) and direction service

[Here is a demo I made](http://daviestrachan.zxq.net/maps/locationtest1.html) for UK with London as a destination
This is the line you need to change

```
 var destinationName    =   "london,uk";    //our destination. Set yours!
```